# how to stop and kill the Twitter4j stream correctly

Tags: streaming, twitter4j

I try to use the Twitter4j streaming features. So my implementation is in the following class :

```
public class TweetsStream {

    private TwitterStream m_twitterstream;
    private StatusListener m_statusListener;

    public void printStream(...)

        // Stream
        m_twitterstream = null;
        m_twitterstream = TwitterStreamFactory.getSingleton();

        // Listener
        m_statusListener = new StatusListenerRedefined(...);
        m_twitterstream.addListener(m_statusListener);

        // Filter
        FilterQuery l_filter = new FilterQuery();
        l_filter.track(... );

        // Launch
        m_twitterstream.filter(l_filter);
    }

    public void stopStream(){

        m_twitterstream.shutdown();
        m_logger.info("shutdown done");

        m_twitterstream = null;
        m_statusListener = null;
    }
}
```

My new StatusListener() prints the status in the console.

Then I create a `TweetsStream` object in another servlet class :

```
@WebServlet("/Controler")
public class Controler extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Logger
    protected final static Logger m_logger = Logger.getLogger("Controler");

    //Stream    
    private TweetsStream m_tweetStream;



    //Function...
    m_tweetStream = new TweetsStream(...);
    m_tweetStream.printStream(...);

}
```

The stream works perfectly. So i try now to stop it. In the same class I have the function :

```
private void stopStream(){
 m_tweetStream.stopStream();
 m_tweetStream = null;
}
```

The stream is stopped in the console, all is fine.

BUT When I recall in the same class my function :

```
    //Function...
    m_tweetStream = new TweetsStream(...);
    m_tweetStream.printStream(...);
```

It is as if i've just resume the previous m_twitterstream with one listener added. So I have two print of each tweet...

How to kill completely the Stream ? And when I relaunch it, how only have the last StatusListener ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution :

The method `TwitterStreamFactory.getSingleton()` returns the same instance of the TwitterStream.

Even if you delete properly your TwitterStream object, the listeners are stored in your TwitterStream Singleton config... So you have to create differents instances of the TwitterStream object with :

```
TwitterStreamFactory l_Twitterfactory = new TwitterStreamFactory();
m_twitterstream = l_Twitterfactory.getInstance();
```

Comment: A note if anyone stumbles upon this post: If you are using authentication, you will have to configure twitter4j via the twitter4j.properties file, because getSingleton() doesn't accept a ConfigurationBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue . Still any of the above solution is not working , So i did a work around for this stored the twitterStream object in a map . so i can get the same object later when i need to close the stream .

```
            ProfileEntity profileEntity = profileRepository.findBySocialId( twitterId+"" ) ;
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerKey( twitterCustomerKey );
            cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret( twitterCustomerSecret );
            cb.setOAuthAccessToken( profileEntity.getAccessToken() ) ; 
            cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret( profileEntity.getAccessTokenSecret() ) ; 
            twitterStream =  new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

> ```
>           twitterStreamMap.put( twitterId , twitterStream ) ;
> ```